# Choosing a warehouse size for Tasks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I came across this question and was puzzled.
How to determine the size of virtual warehouse used for a task?

A. Root task may be executed concurrently (i.e multiple instances), it is recommended to leave some margins in the execution window to avoid missing instances of execution.

B. Querying (select) the size of the stream content would help determine the warehouse size. For ex, if querying large stream content, use a larger warehouse size.

C. If using stored procedure to execute multiple SQL statements, it's best to test run the stored procedure separately to size the compute resource first.

D. Since task infrastructure is based on running the task body on a schedule, it's recommended to configure the virtual warehouse for automatic concurrency handling using Multicluster warehouse to match the task schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new "serverless" Snowflake tasks:

- https://www.snowflake.com/blog/taking-serverless-to-task/

In this case, Snowflake will automatically determine what's the best warehouse size.

You can give a hint to Snowflake on what size to start with, using `USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE`.

> Specifies the size of the compute resources to provision for the first run of the task, before a task history is available for Snowflake to determine an ideal size. Once a task has successfully completed a few runs, Snowflake ignores this parameter setting. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

The implications on billing are described here:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-serverless-billing.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am unable to decide what the correct answer is for the above question though. Is it C or D?

Comment: If you use the new "serverless" feature, then you don't need to worry about it - just let Snowflake determine the best size after a couple runs.

Comment: Yes, very well understood. I am trying to understand this for certification exam perspective. What do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: Oh, that's a different context. I wish the question had said that you were looking for an answer within the certificate exam context. Maybe post on https://reddit.com/r/snowflake (with context), if no one answers here